# python populate elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am very new to Python (previous Matlab user).

I have the array

```
y_pred =  [None] * 128
```

`test_idx` is an array of indeces

```
array([  3,   4,   5,  19,  28,  30,  38,  39,  47,  49,  50,  51,  54,
        64,  74,  81,  84,  85,  90,  91,  93,  97, 102, 103, 106, 107,
       109, 111, 115, 121], dtype=int64)
```

I would like to replace the values of y_pred corresponding to the test_idx with the array `results`

```
array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

if I try

```
y_pred[test_idx] = results
```

I get the error:
**TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index**

Comment: `y_pred` is not an array, but a `list`, which can't be indexed like that. Perhaps use an array instead?

Comment: Also, you should really use the `numpy` tag is you are going to ask a question about `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Do you really want `y_pred`` to be a list of `None`s? Not array of zeros?  What's the Matlab equivalent?

Comment: Show exactly what you expect.  There's too much ambiguity in the current example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: replace `y_pred =  [None] * 128` with `y_pred = np.full(128, np.NaN)`.  Everything else will work once you do that.

Long version:

The problem as others have said, is that `y_pred` is a list, not an array.  Lists do not support getting or setting multiple indexes at a time, you need to use a numpy array for that.

The simplest approach to what you want is to use a numpy array of what is called a "sentinel" value, a value that indicates that nothing was written there.  The most obvious choice for this value is probably either `0` or `NaN`, but depending on what you want to do with the results it could be just about anything.  `NaN` is the closets to `None` you will get in a numerical numpy array, but `0` can make some later calculations easier (for example `NaN != NaN`, you need to use `np.isnan` to identify `NaN` values later).

To do this with zeros, you can replace `y_pred =  [None] * 128` with `y_pred = np.zeros(128)`.  To use `NaN` (or any other value), you can use `y_pred = np.full(128, np.NaN)` (there is also a `np.ones` but I don't think it will help you here).  The rest of your code can then be used as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Your `y_pred` is a native Python list and you cannot index it by anything other than integers. You should create it as a numpy array.

Try to initialize it the way below:

```
import numpy as np
y_pred = np.array([None] * 128)
```

Comment: You have to consider carefully whether or not to use `None`, which will force `y_pred` to have `object` dtype, which kills performance.

Comment: True, but it is a consideration worth mentioning, especially if the OP is new to python/numpy.

Comment: yup, thanks for your comments, this is important thing to mention

Comment: @pt12lol: I believe that you are adressing completely different issue. Indexing with something different than integer is not a problem here.

Comment: @woockashek No, the question is clearly related to `numpy`.

Comment: *"I would like to replace the values of y_pred corresponding to the test_idx with the array"* Where do you see the need for indexing with non-integer value?

Comment: @woockashek `y_pred[test_idx] = results` - here

Answer (score 1):

I see you are doing a lot of matlab here ;)

If you want to do it the pythonic way! you need to loop.
Like:

```
for index, value in zip(test_idx, results):
    y_pred[index] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(test_idx)):
    y_pred[test_idx[i]] = results[i]
```

or:

```
for key, val in zip(test_idx, results):
    y_pred[key] = val
```

I assume your both lists have the same length.